# Is this a valid proof of surjectivity and bijectivity?

Tags: functions

Given a function $F \colon \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ defined by $F(n) = (-1)^n n + 3$ proof that it is surjective.

Since the definition of surjectivity says that $\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}, \ \exists n \in \mathbb{Z} \ \colon k = F(n) = (-1)^n n + 3$ I need to find an expression for $k$ in terms of $n$ and check that $n$ is an integer if $k$ is also an integer.

$k = (-1)^n n + 3 \Longleftrightarrow k - 3 = (-1)^n n$

If $n$ is even I get: $k - 3 = (-1)^n n \Longleftrightarrow k - 3 = n$
If $n$ is odd I get: $k - 3 = (-1)^n n \Longleftrightarrow -(k - 3) = n$

So, in general, $n = (-1)^{k + 1} (k - 3)$.

Since I've found and expression for $n$ in terms of $k$ and, clearly if $k$ is an integer so is $n$ this implies that $F$ is surjective.

Furthermore since this final expression gives for every $k$ an unique $n$ I can say that $F$ is bijective.

Is this argument valid?
How do you prove surjectivity in general?

Comment: It seems fine to me.

Comment: “If $n$ is even” is the wrong approach. You are trying to find $n.$ You should say, “If $k-3$ is even...”

Comment: (Or note that $n$ must be even if and only if $k-3$ is even.)